# Have sed echo string after match

Tags: bash, sed, wget

I need to have the string directly following`/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/`echoed out. This is for a search tool I have created with a bit of help, and everyone recommends **sed**, but I never really use **sed** so I don't understand it well. But here is the script:

```
read -r Username ;\
wget -q -O - https://twitter.com/"${Username}" | \
 sed -n '/data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id=/I \
    {s/^.*data-screen-name=.'"${Username}"'".*data-user-id="\([0-9]*\)".*$/\1/Ip;q}'
```

This script works perfectly fine for most accounts, but if the account is private then it will fail. If it searches instead for`/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/`then only the ID will come up and it doesn't come up with different variables like it does in the original script (that is why it selects the row with `data-screem-name=` I can't use the **twitter** API because I'm exporting this to people who wouldn't even know how to go about obtaining the API and so I'm trying to make it as simple as possible for the user.

I have looked through several SO/SE posts and I don't believe this is a duplicate, so sorry if it is.

EDIT----
This doesn't work on private profiles because the line that it goes to is not inside the HTML. After going through further I noticed that `/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/` gives the ID of the user and is on both private accounts and open accounts.

**Sample data:** 
 Right now, if I were to run this on my account it would work and you would see my ID:

```
Username="thematrix1o1"
717835108540030976
```

But if I run it on a private account I will get no ID (because the line isn't there)

```
Username="touchmytweets"
.
```

(there is no dot in the report, it's just blank)

Here is the image with what I need it to find https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSACJ.jpg
As you can see, her ID is: `726618076633030656`
**Small Sample Report** 
`ile_background_color&quot;:&quot;C0DEED&quot;,&quot;profile_background_image_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png&quot;,&quot;profile_background_image_url_https&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png&quot;,&quot;profile_background_tile&quot;:false,&quot;profile_image_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/`**726618076633030656**`\/wwYbLwbs_normal.jpg&quot;,&quot;profile_image_url_https&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/`**726618076633030656**`\/wwYbLwbs_normal.jpg&quot;,&quot;profile_banner_url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/418265825\/1463628965&quot;,&quot;profile_link_color&quot;:&quot;0084B4&quot;,&quot;profile_sidebar_border_color&quot;:&quot;C0DEED&quot;,&quot;profile_sidebar_fill_color&quot;:&quot;DDEEF6&quot;,&quot;profile_text_color&quot;:&quot;333333&quot;,&quot;profile_use_background_image&quot;:true,&quot;has_extended_profile&quot;:false,&quot;default_profile&quot;:true,&quot;default_profile_image&quot;:false,&quot;following&quot;:null,&quot;follow_request_sent&quot;:null,&quot;notifications&quot;:n`

Comment: I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Please provide an example for the data you receive, and the output you expect.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I have updated the question now. sorry about that.

Comment: So, basically, what you are looking for is  just a `sed` expression that will return the number following "profile_images"?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your output contains any amount of random cruft, and one line you are interested in. Select that line, discard anything but the ID and print the result:

```
 sed -n '/profile_images/s/.*profile_images\\\/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

This could be made slightly more efficient by quitting immediately after that line has been processed.

In fact, that is pretty much exactly what the original code does. The only thing that has changed is the regular expression used.

Comment: This ends up printing the entire set of HTML page into the terminal

Comment: Not for me. Are you sure the sample you posted is accurate?

Comment: the sample i posted is a direct copy from the wget.

Comment: well I was just trying to show what it looked like inside the html when you do the wget, the wget is over 2,200 lines so i didnt want to post that here but ill bin it for you. https://ghostbin.com/paste/ekhzb

Comment: That really surprises me. I copied your sample and ran my solution against it before posting. I just did so again. It prints the user ID and nothing else. Are you using some `sed` implementation other than `GNU sed`?

Comment: i tried it on the sample and it works, but if i use it after wget then it fails and prints the entire thing :/ i need it to run with wget to extract the id

Comment: Well, your sample is pretty much useless.

Comment: I put the sample so you would be able to see where it is instead of posting 2300 lines of html. Thought it would be a time saver. sorry.

Comment: The problem is that the sample is not representative. The other lines are completely different. You should have included part of the surrounding HTML to give a better impression of the problem space.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm confronted with needle-in-haystack work like this, I like to turn it into a line-oriented problem if I can.  You might be able to do that with something like this:

```
$ sed -E 's:[0-9]+:\n&\n:g' filename \
| grep -F -A1 '/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\' | tail -1
```

That puts any digit-string a line by itself, greps for your string, and prints the one after.

It's quite the hack; the right way to parse HTML is with an HTML parser.  But it might get the job done for controlled inputs where you just need one string.

A slightly neater approach would use awk, definitely worth learning if you deal much with such things.